# Python Turtle Weird Behavior When I Reset Screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In the program below, my assumption is that when `screen.clear()` in `reset_game()` is called, all the turtles are destroyed, which I confirm by printing the length of `screen.turtles()` at the end of `reset_game()`. And yet each time `reset_game()` is called, after a short time, more trails are displayed on the screen, which makes no sense to me. Can anyone please explain what the problem is?

```
import turtle
import random

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600

def go_left(tur, screen):
    tur.left(45)

def go_right(tur, screen):
    tur.right(45)

def go_forward(tur, screen):
    tur.forward(10)
    if is_border_collision(tur.pos()):
        game_over(screen)

def go_backward(tur,screen):
    tur.backward(10)
    if is_border_collision(tur.pos()):
        game_over(screen)

def is_border_collision(pos):
    print(pos)
    return pos[0] < (- WIDTH // 2) + 20 or pos[0] > WIDTH // 2 - 20 \
    or pos[1] < (- HEIGHT // 2) + 20 or pos[1] > HEIGHT // 2 - 20

def game_over(screen):
    reset_game(screen)

# GAME LOOP
def game_loop(tina, bob, screen):
    tina.setheading(tina.towards(bob))
    tina.forward(5)
    turtle.ontimer(lambda: game_loop(tina, bob, screen), 100)


def init_screen():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    screen.title("Turtle Game")
    return screen


def reset_game(screen):
    screen.clearscreen()
    screen.bgcolor("green")

    tina = turtle.Turtle()
    tina.shape("turtle")
    tina.color("red")
    tina.pensize(10)
    tina.speed(10)

    bob = turtle.Turtle()
    bob.shape("turtle")
    bob.color("yellow")
    bob.pensize(10)
    bob.penup()
    bob.goto(200, 200)
    bob.pendown()
    bob.speed(10)

    screen.listen()
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    canvas.bind('<Up>', lambda event: go_forward(bob, screen))
    canvas.bind('<Down>', lambda event: go_backward(bob, screen))
    canvas.bind('<Left>', lambda event: go_left(bob, screen))
    canvas.bind('<Right>', lambda event: go_right(bob, screen))

    print(len(screen.turtles()))

    game_loop(tina, bob, screen)


def main():
    screen = init_screen()
    reset_game(screen)
    return "DONE"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg = main()
    print(msg)
    turtle.done()
```

Comment: I don't know if understand the problem correctly but everything works fine for me. When I run your code, I get 2 turtles and can control one of them with my arrow keys.

Comment: "more turtles are displayed on the screen" Are you talking about the trails they left behind? I thought that's a feature :)

Comment: Maybe I should explain more. If you keep playing after a reset, you will soon notice multiple red trails when there should only be one.

Comment: `screen.clear()` doesn't remove turtles. You would have to create turtles only once at start and use always the same turtles instead of creating new turtles again. It also doesn't stops `game_loop` with `ontimer` and it may run all time. You should use some like `if running: turtle.ontimer(...)` to stop it when you set global variable `running = False`

Comment: As far as I know, the tutles can't be destroyed. I simply move the turtles off the screen, or when possible, call Turtle.hideturtle().

Comment: @AnnZen if you look at the result of `print(len(screen.turtles()))`, you'll see they have in theory been destroyed.

Comment: @furas, I think `screen.clear()` does destroy all turtles. The reason I've used it rather than just moving them off screen is that if there are lots of turtles in a program, that approach quickly leads to memory issues and the program will eventually grind to a halt. You are right about the `ontimer()` though. I think the issue is "event stacking" - if I unbind they keys as soon as there is a border collision, and implement your "is_playing" global idea, I can get the code to work properly. I'll post a solution soon if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Okay, maybe you're right. But I guess for my cases, I only want to remove the turtles, not the things in the surroundings.